# Divisibility relation: transitivity proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, relations

[image: Proof]

I'm a bit confused about the proof for this relation. I get the first part, but the second line is where I'm totally muffled!

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**  An example would also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to show that $c\mid(ma+nb)$, in other words, there exists a $k$ such that $ma+nb=ck$. This is exactly what the second line does, it shows that $ma+nb=c(me+nf)$.

Comment: Thank you. The explanation didn't have a "k" so your explanation made it just that bit easier :)

Comment: @zuc0001: No problem! Glad it helped.